How do I position the tooltip always at the same distance from the thumb in the range slider?
I have two range sliders, and I need to position the tooltip in them according to the screenshot.

I placed it, but when moving the slider, the tooltip does not stay at the same distance near it, but moves.
How to solve this problem?
Here is the code -


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.calculator__slider-item');

  sliders.forEach((slider) => {
    const tooltip = slider.nextElementSibling; // Находим tooltip
    const valueDisplay = slider.parentElement.nextElementSibling; // Находим <span> для отображения значения

    function updateSlider() {
      const sliderRect = slider.getBoundingClientRect(); // Получаем размеры слайдера
      const thumbWidth = 20; // Фиксированная ширина thumb
      const min = parseInt(slider.min);
      const max = parseInt(slider.max);

      // Текущее значение
      const value = parseInt(slider.value);

      // Процентное положение слайдера
      const percent = (value - min) / (max - min);

      // Абсолютная позиция thumb в пикселях
      const thumbPosition = percent * sliderRect.width;

      // Позиционируем tooltip строго по thumb
      tooltip.style.left = `${thumbPosition - tooltip.offsetWidth / 2 + thumbWidth / 2}px`;
      tooltip.textContent = value;

      // Обновляем отображение значения
      valueDisplay.textContent = value;
    }

    // Инициализация
    updateSlider();

    // Обновление при взаимодействии
    slider.addEventListener('input', updateSlider);
  });
});
.slider-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.calculator__slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.calculator__tooltip {
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 140%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.calculator__slider-item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  min-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
}

.calculator__slider-item::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #26bb01;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -410px 0 0 400px #26bb01;
}
<div class="calculator__item slider-group">
  <div class="calculator__slider">
    <label for="hours">Часов в день</label>
    <div class="calculator__slider-wrapper">
      <input type="range" id="hours" min="2" max="12" value="8" class="calculator__slider-item" />
      <div class="calculator__tooltip"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="calculator__slider-value" id="hours-value">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator__slider">
    <label for="days">Дней в месяц</label>
    <div class="calculator__slider-wrapper">
      <input type="range" id="days" min="3" max="31" value="20" class="calculator__slider-item" />
      <div class="calculator__tooltip"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="calculator__slider-value" id="days-value">20</span>
  </div>
</div>



https://codepen.io/lqwhvtss-the-flexboxer/pen/oNKRydz
I tried different variations of calculating the tooltip position in js - nothing worked

You need to be careful here, what width you actually base your percentage calculation on. First of all, your input field is wider than the wrapper - because you added padding to 100% width. And then you got different amounts of padding on either side of the input, meaning you won't even move the slider button over the whole width of the input field. You need to take that into account.

transform: translateY(-50%) would center the tooltip around its assigned left position. IMHO it would be better, if you just positioned the tooltip from the right of the wrapper - then it will be easier, to make the right-most number always have the same distance from the button, regardless of whether the tooltip value is two or just one digit. (If you center it around its own width, you'll get a little "jump" when it switches between one and two digits.(

How should this look when the value reaches 0? How should it look when it reaches the end? What are the design requirements for these cases?

@KostasMinaidis In the screenshot, the first slider is the maximum value. The minimum value cannot be zero. Here is a screenshot of how it should look, only for place 20 there will be 3. https://paste.pics/d4e5b721b9bd4c95f5fd3e578a7d5c78
